# How to compute probability

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution, naive-bayes, bayes

I have a dataset consisting of 4000 observation from each 324 continuous  features are extracted. Each observation has been labeled a class. Since each feature from that dataset is continuous, have I created a distribution describing how each feature is distributed for each class.

I want to use the distribution i computed, for classification purposes.. Which Naive bayes method also do for continuous datasets.

The reason why I want to compute is purely based on some observation I made with naive bayes. I created multiple models using naive bayes, and tried to predict the same sample, and for reason were the model favoring a specific class rather than the right one which the label says.

I then made a plot of the distribution I computed earlier, and saw that one class in peticular, have a high density of occurring which also were the class which was favored in the test using naive bayes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKpSr.png

I tried using the probabilities to get from the distributions to compute the probability of a sample belonging to the different class, but i am not getting any results which reside towards the class (class1) which was favored before, i think i may compute it incorrectly?

This is how i Compute it :

```
for( i in 1:10)
{
  out <- 0
  for(j in 1:324 )
  {
    print(i)
    est = norm_dist_res_fewer_muld[[paste0(i,"-",j)]]$estimate
    out<-out + pnorm(G2M2$data[[500,j]], est[1],est[2])
  }  
  output[i] <- out
}
```

G2M2$data is just my test dataset. and norm_dist_res_fewer_muld  is an `fittest`object.

Comment: How many classes are you dealing with? Just to be clear, each observation has been assigned to one among k classes, right?

Comment: Your second and third paragraphs are not very clear. I have been trying, but I failed to get what they intend to say. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I am dealing with 10 classes . and yes they pre assigned to one class.

Comment: I rephrased it, hope it makes sense

Comment: This question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208115/10-class-problems-with-324-features-am-i-recognition-class-based-on-multiple-f Seems strongly related to your question.